# Perform different operations using same template file for two different buttons

Tags: html, django

I have two buttons in my browser, which has the same template. A Popup is opened upon clicking these two buttons. The Popup has an input text field which has to display different values with respect to the click of the button. I'm using common template, view and controller for both the buttons. The code in my template file looks like:

```
<td><input type="text" class="col-md-10" maxlength="256" ng-if="title1" ng-show="'{{reviewtit}}'" ng-model="arform.revtitle"  required/></td>

              <td><input type="text" class="col-md-10" maxlength="256" ng-init="'{{reviewtit}}'" ng-model="arform.revtitle"  > {{reviewtit}} </td>
```

Views:

```
class SiverifyAddReviewView(JSONResponseMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "siverify_add_review.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        latest_id = SiverifyVerificationSiteRevision.objects.order_by('-id').first().id
        context = super(SiverifyAddReviewView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        latest_id =latest_id+1
        context['reviewtit'] = 'Review_' + str(latest_id) + '_' + time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        context['ngapp'] = 'ReviewMod'
```

In the above code, title1 is a value I get from controller and {{reviewtit}} is a value from views. I need these two values to be displayed when respective type of button is clicked. Which is the best way to do this? I surfed quite a bit about specifying an ng-if here in the template or creating a custom API. Nothing seems to workout. Is there any easier way? Right now I'm able to see only the 'title1' value which I generate from the controller. The other button doesn't even show the input field. New approaches welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Getting your view would help to debug your code.

Comment: Added views in the code